# Prevent Microsoft Access 2010 from connecting to Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

i want to edit a ms access App, is there a way to prevent it from attemping to connect to the remote database? i mean i don't want to use the app, i just want to edit some forms, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If Sql Server is accepting connections on port 1433, maybe you could block your local computer's port via a firewall rule.  But be careful, the newer "by instance" sql servers sometimes don't have a hard-port they are using.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the database to your local drive and unplug your network cable.

Comment: First, Grumpy Cat rules!  Second.  Great idea (about the network cable)!  Third, if you see the "Stevie Wonder" "I just called to say I love you" Grumpy Cat, I ~created~ that one!

Comment: @granadaCoder lol thank you and I love your meme, and Grumpy Cat in general.